# Regex in R to extract utterances that satisfy negative positional condition

Tags: r, regex

I've got a large number of utterances each containing the word 'well' in various positions in the utterance. Here's some illustrative data:

```
data <- c("well what the church meeting 's got to decide",
        "oh well yes those are those are normal things",
        "well they 've sent you a letter from hospital",
        "and i think well you cheeky sod you know",
        "'cos she 's well that day albert took me",
        "yeah well you 're going out anyway so you")
```

I'd like to extract those utterances that satisfy a *negative* *positional* *criterion*: that 'well' is not the first or second word in the utterance. The expected result is this:

```
data <- c("and i think well you cheeky sod you know",
        "'cos she 's well that day albert took me")
```

This pattern gets me what I do *not* want to extract:

```
grep("^well|^\\w*\\swell", data, perl = T, value = T)
[1] "well what the church meeting 's got to decide" "oh well yes those are those are normal things"
[3] "well they 've sent you a letter from hospital" "yeah well you 're going out anyway so you"
```

Now the trick would be to *negate* this pattern. I've tried negative lookahead, but it does not work:

```
grep("(?!^well|^\\w*\\swell)", data, perl = T, value = T)
[1] "well what the church meeting 's got to decide" "oh well yes those are those are normal things"
[3] "well they 've sent you a letter from hospital" "and i think well you cheeky sod you know"     
[5] "'cos she 's well that day albert took me"      "yeah well you 're going out anyway so you"
```

What regex in R would perform the sought extraction? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `invert=TRUE` to reverse your `grep` results and your pattern can be simplified a bit:

```
> data <- c("well what the church meeting 's got to decide",
+         "oh well yes those are those are normal things",
+         "well they 've sent you a letter from hospital",
+         "and i think well you cheeky sod you know",
+         "'cos she 's well that day albert took me",
+         "yeah well you 're going out anyway so you")
> grep("^\\s*(?:\\w+\\s+)?well\\b", data, value=TRUE, invert=TRUE)
[1] "and i think well you cheeky sod you know"
[2] "'cos she 's well that day albert took me"
```

There is no need to use the PCRE engine to run this pattern.

**Regex details**

- `^` - start of string
- `\\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(?:\\w+\\s+)?` - a non-capturing group matching:

  - `\\w+` - 1+ word chars
  - `\\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `well\\b` - a whole word `well` (`\b` is a word boundary).